# proguard is ok, but running App error...help me

Tags: android, proguard, picasso

```
08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657] No pending exception expected: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativePlatformThread" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void net.daum.mf.map.n.api.internal.NativeMapGraphicsViewGles.onSizeChangedMapView(int, int, int, int) ((null):-2)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void net.daum.a.a.g.a(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10, int, int) ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void android.opengl.a.a$m.i() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void android.opengl.a.a$m.a() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657]   at void net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativeThread.run() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.796 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/thread.cc:1657] 

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Runtime aborting...

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Aborting thread:

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "GLThread 5935" prio=7 tid=14 Runnable

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12dca3a0 self=0xce736900

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=2675 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xd0a25920

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=R schedstat=( 6549303 328885 52 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=7 HZ=100

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xd0923000-0xd0925000 stackSize=1038KB

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 0034e655  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 0032ee11  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+308)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 00321e89  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState10DumpThreadERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEPNS_6ThreadE+24)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #03 pc 00321cd3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+362)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #04 
pc 00318aab  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+90)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 000b4ac1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+864)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 0033219f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread24AssertNoPendingExceptionEv+602)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #07 pc 000e4765  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+28)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #08 pc 0025fd8b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+1878)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #09 pc 000c5a10  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit18getJavaClassByNameEP7_JNIEnvPKc+16)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #10 pc 000c63ac  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit21PlatformThreadAndroid5startEv+60)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #11 pc 000cdb48  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN7mapCore25BasicAsyncTaskWorkerGroup12startWorkersEi+76)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #12 pc 000cded4  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN7mapCore16AsyncTaskManager19onInitializeManagerEv+80)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #13 pc 0008fa64  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit11BaseManager17initializeManagerEv+36)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #14 pc 000b4e00  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN9mapEngine22MapEngineModuleManager17initializeMapViewERKN13mobileToolkit6Size2DE+176)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #15 pc 00083a90  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (Java_net_daum_mf_map_n_api_internal_NativeMapGraphicsViewGles_onSizeChangedMapView+104)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #16 pc 0006786d  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_net_daum_mf_map_n_api_internal_NativeMapGraphicsViewGles_onSizeChangedMapView__IIII+104)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.mf.map.n.api.internal.NativeMapGraphicsViewGles.onSizeChangedMapView(Native method)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.a.a.g.a(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.opengl.a.a$m.i(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.opengl.a.a$m.a(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativeThread.run(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativePlatformThread" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at void net.daum.mf.map.n.api.internal.NativeMapGraphicsViewGles.onSizeChangedMapView(int, int, int, int) ((null):-2)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at void net.daum.a.a.g.a(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10, int, int) ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at void android.opengl.a.a$m.i() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at void android.opengl.a.a$m.a() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at void net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativeThread.run() ((null):-1)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] All threads:

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] DALVIK THREADS (21):

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419] "GLThread 5935" prio=7 tid=14 Runnable

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12dca3a0 self=0xce736900

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | sysTid=2675 nice=-4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xd0a25920

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | state=R schedstat=( 33844533 2346386 88 ) utm=2 stm=1 core=6 HZ=100

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | stack=0xd0923000-0xd0925000 stackSize=1038KB

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #00 pc 0034e655  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+128)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #01 pc 0032ee11  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+308)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #02 pc 00340e71  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art14DumpCheckpoint3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+620)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #03 pc 0033ac7b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList13RunCheckpointEPNS_7ClosureE+330)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #04 pc 0033a9a1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10ThreadList4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEb+180)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #05 pc 00321cdd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art10AbortState4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEE+372)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #06 pc 00318aab  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+90)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #07 pc 000b4ac1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+864)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #08 pc 0033219f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread24AssertNoPendingExceptionEv+602)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #09 pc 000e4765  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ClassLinker9FindClassEPNS_6ThreadEPKcNS_6HandleINS_6mirror11ClassLoaderEEE+28)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #10 pc 0025fd8b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI9FindClassEP7_JNIEnvPKc+1878)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #11 pc 000c5a10  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit18getJavaClassByNameEP7_JNIEnvPKc+16)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #12 pc 000c63ac  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit21PlatformThreadAndroid5startEv+60)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #13 pc 000cdb48  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN7mapCore25BasicAsyncTaskWorkerGroup12startWorkersEi+76)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #14 pc 000cded4  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN7mapCore16AsyncTaskManager19onInitializeManagerEv+80)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #15 pc 0008fa64  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN13mobileToolkit11BaseManager17initializeManagerEv+36)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #16 pc 000b4e00  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (_ZN9mapEngine22MapEngineModuleManager17initializeMapViewERKN13mobileToolkit6Size2DE+176)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #17 pc 00083a90  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/lib/arm/libDaumMapEngineApi.so (Java_net_daum_mf_map_n_api_internal_NativeMapGraphicsViewGles_onSizeChangedMapView+104)

08-15 22:01:08.884 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   native: #18 pc 0006786d  /data/app/com.grapeproject.playyonsei-1/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_net_daum_mf_map_n_api_internal_NativeMapGraphicsViewGles_onSizeChangedMapView__IIII+104)

08-15 22:01:08.885 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.mf.map.n.api.internal.NativeMapGraphicsViewGles.onSizeChangedMapView(Native method)

08-15 22:01:08.885 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.a.a.g.a(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.885 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.opengl.a.a$m.i(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.885 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at android.opengl.a.a$m.a(unavailable:-1)

08-15 22:01:08.885 2636-2675/? A/art: art/runtime/runtime.cc:419]   at net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativeThread.run(unavailable:-1)
```

gradle:

[image]

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Hi

I am a Korean developer.

I have a problem and I post it.

I created the application using the picasso API.
Proguard has a picasso warring.

so

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView {*; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp. **
```

I've added and fixed the issue.

However, when you run the application, an error occurs.

I want to find a problem. Help.

Answer (score 0):

In your **Gradle** make the `minifyEnabled` `false` and the `zipAlignEnabled` `false`

```
minifyEnabled false
zipAlignEnabled false
```

Comment: in your Gradle make false the minifyEnabled false
zipAlignEnabled false

Answer (score 0):

the ProGuard configuration is obviously "not ok", hence the error message reads ...

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "net.daum.mf.map.n.api.NativePlatformThread"

you'd require a ProGuard configuration about like this:

```
# to keep the NativePlatformThread:
-keep class net.daum.mf.map.n.** { *; }

# these might not be optional:
-keep class net.daum.mf.map.api.MapView { *; }
-keep class net.daum.android.map.location.MapViewLocationManager { *; }
-keep class net.daum.mf.map.api.MapPolyline { *; }
-keep class net.daum.mf.map.api.MapPoint** { *; }
```

while reading the "daum" [documentation](http://apis.map.daum.net/android/documentation/) is suggested.